# How do I work with equations that are passed on in the goal/query of prolog?

Tags: prolog, predicate, equation, clpq

I have this scenario wherein I get a linear equation in the Prolog query like below:

```
?- myquery( 3X + 5Y = 10, Result).
```

So my query has an equation 3X + 5Y = 10, which in general assumes the form AX + BY = C, where A=3, B=5 and C=10.

Now, in my prolog program, I am trying to define a predicate that can take in the expression mentioned in the query above. That is, I somehow want to get A, B and C values and also the operator involved (in the above case the plus operator) stored and then used on the logic that I define withing the program. I am wondering how this can be done.

To be more generic, the question is how do I identify the constants and the operator involved in an equation that is passed on through the goal/query?

Comment: what implementation of prolog are you using? it appears that in swi-prolog you cannot have an argument of the form you described (3X + 5Y = 10)

Comment: I am looking for eclipse prolog, but anything should be fine, I just need to get the concepts right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following transcript may prove illuminating:

```
32 ?- Term = (3*_X + 5*_Y = 10), functor(Term,F,A).

Term = 3*_G527+5*_G530=10
F = =
A = 2 

33 ?- Term = (3*_X + 5*_Y = 10), arg(Arg,Term,Val).

Term = 3*_G459+5*_G462=10
Arg = 1
Val = 3*_G459+5*_G462 ; % user pressed ';' interactively

Term = 3*_G459+5*_G462=10
Arg = 2
Val = 10 ; % user pressed ';' interactively

No
35 ?- Term = (3*_X + 5*_Y = 10), arg(1,Term,Val1), functor(Val1,F1,A1),
      arg(2,Val1,Val12).

Term = 3*_G693+5*_G696=10
Val1 = 3*_G693+5*_G696
F1 = +
A1 = 2
Val12 = 5*_G696
```

The last query reads: for `Term` as given, 1st `arg` of `Term` is `Val1`, the functor of `Val1` is `F1` with arity `A1` (meaning, it has `A1` args - subparts - itself), and 2nd `arg` of the term in `Val1` is stored under `Val12` name. To clarify, any symbolic data in Prolog is in the form of `fff(aa,bb,cc,...)` where `fff` is some name, called *functor*, and the "arguments" in that expression can be accessed through the `arg` call.

That means that the original expression `(3*_X + 5*_Y = 10)` is actually stored in Prolog as `'='( '+'( '*'(3,_X), '*'(5,_Y)), 10)`. When you get to the atomic parts (functors with arity 0), you can check them further:

```
47 ?- arg(1,(3*X),V), functor(V,F,A), number(V).

X = _G441
V = 3
F = 3
A = 0 

Yes
```

**EDIT:** to answer your other question (from the comments):

```
1 ?- (3*_X + 5*_Y = 10) = (A*X + B*Y = C).

A = 3
X = _G412
B = 5
Y = _G415
C = 10 

Yes
```

If you insist on not writing out the multiplication sign `*` explicitly, you will have to represent your terms as strings, and to analyze that string. That would be a much more involved task.

**EDIT:** another thing to try is `=..` predicate, called "Univ":

```
4 ?- (3*_X + 5*_Y = 10) =.. X.

X = [=, 3*_G454+5*_G457, 10] 

Yes
5 ?- (3*_X + 5*_Y = 10) =.. X, X=[X1,X2,X3], X2 =.. Y.

X = [=, 3*_G545+5*_G548, 10]
X1 = =
X2 = 3*_G545+5*_G548
X3 = 10
Y = [+, 3*_G545, 5*_G548] 

Yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.. I seem to get the logic now. Let me try it out.

Comment: @kallakafar btw in case you didn't know that, here in Stackoverflow you can *accept* an answer if/which you think answers your question, by clicking on big empty green check-mark (V-shaped) next to it. It will give some reputation points (15 ?) to the author. Also, it is possible to "up-vote" an answer, which gives it 10 reputation points. Part of the SO experience. :)

Comment: yep, i did try to upvote this answer, but then it said i need to have 15 points myself to do that, which unfortunately i dont. i didnt mark it as answered so that i can try it out myself, and maybe post followup questions. :) i will, once i am done..for sure! thanks, Will.

Comment: @kallakafar I've added some more example code to the answer, check it out. :)

Comment: Thank You, @Will Ness. I am still trying your solutions out,but I think I have got your point. I will update this post if I have anymore questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog has a constraint [library clp(Q,R)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.8%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpqr.html%27%29%29) that solve at symbolic level these equations:

```
[debug]  ?- [library(clpq)].
% library(clpq) compiled into clpq 0,27 sec, 992 clauses
true.

?- {3 * X + 5 * Y = 10}.
{Y=2-3 rdiv 5*X}.
```

Eclipse will surely have something more advanced. These libraries aren't simple, tough...

Of interest to you, the Prolog syntax is used, as a *host language*, so the usual builtins could be applied for identify vars, constants, and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use term inspection predicates: arg/3, functor/3, var/1, (=..)/2 etc.

Comment: Umm.. could you please elaborate on how to get 3 stored in A1, x as A2, 5 as B1, Y as B2 and 10 as C (from the example I have given in main question)..? I'm still struggling on how to use arg (or for that matter functor/3, var/1 etc..) for the example I have cited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at examples of symbolic differentiation implemented using term rewrite rules; they handle such expressions.

Here's a chapter (minus 1 page) from the book Clause and Effect that you might find useful:
[Clause and Effect - Chapter Six: Term Rewriting](http://books.google.com/books?id=fbYjjEn6a_4C&lpg=PA69&ots=sphfpOafZc&dq=prolog%20term-rewrite%20symbolic-differentiation&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q=prolog%20term-rewrite%20symbolic-differentiation&f=false)

Another from The art of Prolog: advanced programming techniques
[23 An equation solver](http://books.google.com/books?id=w-XjuvpOrjMC&lpg=PA439&ots=4Xz3XNF0Mw&dq=programming%20in%20prolog%20symbolic%20differentiation&pg=PA439#v=onepage&q=programming%20in%20prolog%20symbolic%20differentiation&f=false)

[Programming in Prolog](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540583505) also has a section (7.11) on symbolic differentiation.